# Why isn't this CSS rule being applied?

Tags: html, reactjs, less, stylesheet

I want all the text fonts to use `Roboto` by default, but also for one specific class to use `Roboto Thin`. Here is my code so far:

### mixins.less

```
* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

### fast-payment.less

```
@import (reference) '../../content/less/mixins';
.bss-fast-payment {
  &__header {
    .useAlsSectorFont();
  }
}
```

### Chrome DevTools

[image: Google Chrome DevTools.]

Comment: Try to aviod `*` selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally found out how to do it. The only thing I changed was to put bss-fast-payment__header .

**mixins.less**

```
* {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

**fast-payment.less**

```
@import (reference) '../../content/less/mixins';
.bss-fast-payment {
  &__header * {
    .useAlsSectorFont();
  }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of adding this as an answer - but what's happening here is now you have made that rule on top **more specific** than the previous rule (just `*`), so `.class *` is actually preferred over `*`.

Answer (score 3):

The `*` selector is overriding the `.bss-fast-payment__header` class selector. You can use:

```css
font-family: 'Roboto Thin', sans-serif !important;
```

to force an override. Try to avoid doing this too often, and try to avoid the `*` selector as well.

Comment: This is still somewhat surprising to me: I wouldn't have expected the universal selector to have higher specificity.

Answer (score 0):

Use !Important with font-family that are getting override with child class.